# Why does Chrome warn about TLS1.1 while Firefox uses TLS1.2?

Tags: google-chrome, tls1.2

The chrome devtools made me aware that we should upgrade our web server to TLS 1.2, so we did. The lock icon shown in Firefox showed an exclamation mark until the upgrade.

But now the chrome devtools tell me:

```
The connection used to load resources from https://mltest.omegam.nl used TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1,
which are deprecated and will be disabled in the future. 
Once disabled, users will be prevented from loading these resources. 
The server should enable TLS 1.2 or later.
```

This really puzzles me.

*Why does Firefox use TLS1.2 and on the same site Chrome use TLS1.1?*

I could disable the old TLS 1.0 and 1.1, but after some looking around I saw that many sites still enable those, including google.com itself. I don't like to disable the old versions and risk that one of our customers cannot use the site. My boss won't be happy.

I found some info on a Windows Registry setting for 'chrome min ssl', but I find it strange to tell every browser which version it should use, I assume that every browser uses the best version that is available.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers support different ciphers. It’s possible Chrome does not support the only ciphers you have set up for TLSv1.2. Chrome is quite strict about retiring old ciphers.

Run your site though [this tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) for more information.